# How can i show 2 position value as default in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

Like i have 10 values in Spinner (0-9 positions). What if i would like to show 2 position value as default in spinner in onCreate()...

Comment: I don't think this should be voted down

Comment: How did you populate the Spinner.

Comment: How did you set the spinner?

Comment: Your `cityArrayList` is empty. why is that?

Comment: Your cityArrayList is empty. you have to add data to your arraylist

Comment: Show your parsing code. If you'r using `AsyncTask` then update your `UI` in `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: @Boss check my updated code...  and try to understand oncreate i am trying to show spinner value same as getting from database

Comment: @PiyushGupta check my updated code... and try to understand oncreate i am trying to show spinner value same as getting from database

Comment: @Sheychan check my updated code... and try to understand oncreate i am trying to show spinner value same as getting from database

Comment: @RajeshJadav check my updated code... and try to understand oncreate i am trying to show spinner value same as getting from database

Comment: @Sophie: As pointed out by other guys you are creating your spinner adapter using `cityArrayList ` but you are not adding any item to this `ArrayList`. This is the reason your spinner is blank. Add some items in it and you will be good to go.

Comment: also did you forget to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding content to your `cityArrayList` ??

Comment: @Boss May be i have not explained it well, i am able to fetch and show values in spinner from json (no problem here)
now user makes login and i have to show exact city in spinner by default what he/she has chosen earlier (this getting from database in String)
Here i am facing issue because i don't understand how to show that value as default value in spinner ?

Comment: @Sophie `spinnerCity.setSelection(position);` should work.

Comment: first setup the Spinner then you will only setSelection() after it

Comment: @Boss In a same way i am trying to show if strPHPCity is Delhi then show 0 position as default and else  Banglore but still not getting data in Spinner if(strPHPCity.equals("Delhi")) {
     spinnerCity.setSelection(0);
    }
    else if (strPHPCity.equals("Banglore")) {
     spinnerCity.setSelection(1);
    }

Comment: @Sophie The spinner is blank because there is no data to show. `spinnerCity.setSelection(1)` This code does not make the spinner blank. you should double check that you are setting data to your spinner correctly.

Comment: @Boss I hope you can resolve this issue, and check my updated code: http://paste.ofcode.org/hPW2pEuBiQ7LWZYAgAXSrd

Comment: @Sophie You haven't updated your dataset after parsing. call this `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `postExecute()` method. check @Rohit5k2 's answer

Comment: yes i have made changes, and try to understand my issue: http://paste.ofcode.org/39LCV67PHghDqXMwdBkALL4 : // here i am facing issue (in Spinner always showing Delhi as default, whereas strPHPCity = "Banglore" so why its not showing Banglore as default)
    if(strPHPCity == "Delhi") {
     spinnerCity.setSelection(0);
    }
    else if (strPHPCity == "Banglore"){
     spinnerCity.setSelection(1);
    }
   } @Boss

Comment: @Sophie see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By seeing your code from your [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/hPW2pEuBiQ7LWZYAgAXSrd) you haven't called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.Please check that. You should call it in the `postExecute()` method

And also please use `.equals()` to check `String` values instead of `==`. That may be your issue.

```
if(strPHPCity.equals("Delhi")) {
    spinnerCity.setSelection(0);
} else if (strPHPCity.equals("Banglore")) {
     spinnerCity.setSelection(1);
}
```

Comment: still facing same issue

Comment: Ok. please update your code in your link or post here

Comment: I used it in onPostExecute() method.. and it worked :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other guys you are creating your spinner adapter using `cityArrayList` but you are not adding any item to this `ArrayList`. This is the reason your spinner is blank. You should refresh your adapter once data is available.

This is how you should do it.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if(result == false)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mySpinner.setSelection(2)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the spinner to show anything when adapter is empty? Please check the question it is creating a blank array list and its nowhere refreshed.

Comment: Or simply I should give only one solution. Editing.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 May be i have not explained it well, i am able to fetch and show values in spinner from json (no problem here)
now user makes login and i have to show exact city in spinner by default what he/she has chosen earlier (this getting from database in String)
Here i am facing issue because i don't understand how to show that value as default value in spinner ?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 check updated question: Like i have 10 values in Spinner (0-9 positions). What if i would like to show 2 position value as default in spinner in onCreate()...

Comment: Why don't you just use `mySpinner.setSelection(2)` in `onPostExecute()`. See my edit.

Comment: check my complete code, now its showing Delhi as default: http://paste.ofcode.org/hPW2pEuBiQ7LWZYAgAXSrd